# Как удаленно деинсталлировать ПО с нескольких ПК средствами Active Directory

Tags: windows, администрирование, active-directory

Как удалить программы удаленно сразу на нескольких (~200) ПК?

Список программ: Adobe Acrobat XI, WinRar, Adobe Photoshop CS6, и т.д.

Клиентские машины: ПО Windows 7, 8, 8,1, 10.

Мне доступна Active Directory.

Comment: Дайте хоть какую-нибудь конкретику. Что именно вы удаляете, какая ОС на рабочих станциях, какие средства администрирования вам доступны.

Comment: Вопрос интересный, но нужны детали. Пожалуйста, ответьте на вопросы Павла. Отредактируйте вопрос с помощью кнопки [edit].

Comment: Да. Вопрос интересный. Будут детали - можно начать советовать.

Comment: Поправил спасибо

Answer (score 1):

**Если эти программы были установлены через GPO**

Удалить их можно через ту же самую политику. Для этого заходим в редактор политики, разворачиваем ветку нужной конфигурации `Computer configuration\Policies\Software settings\Software instalation`.

Находим там нужный софт и убеждаемся, что в его свойствах на вкладке `Развертывание (Deployment)` стоит флажок `Удалять это приложение, если его использование выходит за рамки, допустимые политикой управления (Uninstall this application when it falls out of the scope of management)` если нет, ставим.

Далее выходим из свойств, кликаем правой кнопкой на приложении Все задачи (All tasks) -> Удалить (Remove). В открывшемся окне выбираем `Немедленное удаление этого приложения с компьютеров всех пользователей (Immediately uninstall the software from users and computers)`.

**Если не через GPO**

Первый вариант:

Находим на целевых ПК ветку реестра `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` там лежит список установленных программ локальной машины. И есть директивы под названием `UninstallString` примерно такого вида `MsiExec.exe /I{идентификатор}` это как раз команда, которую нужно выполнить для удаления конкретного ПО. Вам нужно узнать эти команды для кождого ПО, которые вы хотите удалить, по идее они у одной и той же версии софта не отличаются.

Второй вариант:

использовать встроенные деинсталяторы. Они как правило лежат в `C:\Program Files\Имя софта\uninstall.exe` но для них нужно искать ключи "тихого запуска", чтобы отрабатывало без диалоговых окон.

Третий вариант:

Просто «нагуглить» UninstallString для каждого ПО. Их часто пишут в официальной документации, а так же на форумах по теме.

Дальше нужно написать скрипт выполняющий найденные команды на powershell или vba и навесить его на netlogon. Что-то вроде этого, но с вашими строками запуска:

```
Set objWshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
On Error Resume Next 
objWshShell.Run "msiexec.exe /X{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000} /qn", 1, True
WScript.quit
```

Далее кладем файл скрипта в доступную для чтения сетевую папку.

Создаем новую политику, заходим в ветку `Conputer configuration\Windows settiong\Scripts (Startup/Shutdown)` и добавляем его там.

Применяем политику к целевым компьютерам.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 0):

Можно средствами PowerShell:

```
$Computers = Get-ADComputer -Filter *
Foreach ($Computer in $Computers)
{
  $Hostname = $Computer.Name
  $apps = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Product -ComputerName wks-pc11s22 |where name -Like "WinRar*"
  $apps.uninstall()
}
```

Но эта команда может не видеть всех программ, установленных на компьютере. Если версия Windows более современная (последние 10 и 11), то можно удалять командой `Invoke-Command -ComputerName $Computer.Name -ScriptBlock { Get-Package -Name "WinRar*" | Uninstall-Package}`